# Masking Credit Card Numbers in Sharepoint newform?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint new form, where I want user to enter his description of issue and where he can mention the list of 'Credit Card Numbers' . As its a PII information I want the credit card numbers enetered by User to be masked in some way.
I use Sharepoint Designer 2010 only, so please provide me some option on how this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store PII data in SharePoint.
If you're using Designer, connect to a SQL datastore as a separate datasource.  Technically, you'd be creating a SharePoint Web Application (not to be confused with a SharePoint Web Application within IIS and as a root of the farm).

We've done this many times within DoD organizations.  SharePoint is not secure, and too many things can happen.  It makes more sense to add that additional layer of security and abstraction by keeping the data in a separate SQL database, rather than in SharePoint lists.  Remember, a user can always create a custom view, which will throw away all of the security your custom form may seem to provide.